# Woocommerce Additional Message on Product Variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I have a Wordpress website build with Woocommcerce. I want to add some extra fields for users to be able to personalize their products ( some text inputs for them to write whatever  they want). I thinks this needs to be done with custom attributes but I'm not sure.

I have tried this to add an extra attribute type:

```
add_filter("product_attributes_type_selector" , function( $array ){
    $array["textfield"] = __( 'Textfield', 'woocommerce' );
    return $array ;
});
```

I have no idea where to go on from this or if this is the right approach.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I don't want to use any plugins, so don't recommend any please

Comment: Yup it's a ok solution, this also needs so to also saved as product meta and added to the order, figured it on my own eventually but this is a good topic if someone needs to this in the future. Thanks @LoicTheAztec

Comment: I have maid similar complete answers related, so if you search a bit, you will find all the process and hooks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`** action hook, that will add a custom input text field before quantities field and add to cart button on variable products only:

```
// Adding a custom input text field before quantities field and add to cart button on variable products only
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_fields' , 10, 0 );
function custom_product_fields() {
    global $product;

    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return; // Only for variable products

    echo '<div class="product-custom-fields">
        <label class="my-custom-field1" for="custom_textfield1">'.__( 'Label text: ', 'woocommerce' ).'<br>
            <input type="text" name="custom_textfield1" class="input-text" placeholder="'.__( 'Enter a text', 'woocommerce' ).'" value="">
        </label>
    </div>
    <br clear="all">';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works… so you will get something like:

[image]

You will use instead **`woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`** action hook, if you want to display this custom field under add to cart button,

> But you should need **to save** this custom field in cart object when added to cart and to **display it** in cart and checkout pages too.